# New "org.springframework.data.geo" package/API in Spring Data Commons

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-commons

I noticed the introduction of a new package/API related to geo spacial concepts in Spring Data Commons: `org.springframework.data.geo`.

It is officially described as follows:

> Value types representing geo-spatial concepts.

This is quite succinct. Can someone please provide some sample use cases for this API?